Upload drive attachments using Google Sheets app script with cells dictating destination folders
I am trying to create a method to upload files based on categories but I want each file to go to a respective folder.  Current method works with a folder ID already inputed into the script.
Custom menu button needs "attach file _____" with respective category when inputting.
Folder ID's will be ready and identified.
Google spreadsheet, with the script, will have an "admin/settings" sheet with folder ID's in a single column.
How can I reference the column with folder ID's so the script will save it to the proper folder?
Folder ID's will be listed in, ADMIN! A2-A9
// Use this code for Google Docs, Slides, Forms, or Sheets.
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
 .createMenu('Upload File')
 .addItem('Attachment', 'openAttachmentDialog')
 .addToUi();
}
function openAttachmentDialog() {
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('UploadFile');
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
 .showModalDialog(html, 'Upload File');
}
function saveFile(obj) {
 var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
 var file = DriveApp.getFolderById("1J5naBr1_PPgTLNpJsgro3r77yDJLmXTr").createFile(blob);
 var cellFormula = 'hyperlink("' + file.getUrl() + '";"' + file.getName() + '")';
 
 var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var selection = activeSheet.getSelection();
 var cell = selection.getCurrentCell();
 cell.setFormula(cellFormula);
 
 return file.getId();
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
  <script>
    function getFiles() {
      document.getElementById("uploadButton").disabled = true;
      const progressText = document.getElementById("progress");
      const f = document.getElementById('files');
      var uploadCompletedCount = 0;
      progressText.innerHTML = "Uploading file " + (uploadCompletedCount + 1) + "/" + [...f.files].length + "";
      [...f.files].forEach((file, i) => {
        const fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = (e) => {
          const data = e.target.result.split(",");
          const obj = {fileName: f.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((id) => {
            uploadCompletedCount++;
            progressText.innerHTML = "Upload completed";
            if (uploadCompletedCount >= [...f.files].length){
              google.script.host.close();
            }
            else{
              progressText.innerHTML = "Uploading file " + (uploadCompletedCount + 1) + "/" + [...f.files].length + "";
            }
          }).saveFile(obj);
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
      });
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <!-- <input type="file" name="upload" id="files" multiple/> -->
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="files"/> <!-- I expect to up load only one file -->
    <input type='button' id="uploadButton" value='Upload' onclick='getFiles()' class="action"> 
    <br><br>
    <div id="progress"> </div>
  </body>
</html>


If you had used my proposed scripts(res1 and ref2), I apologize that my proposed scripts were not useful for your situation. About your question, I cannot understand the relationship between the files and the folders. Also, I cannot understand Custom menu button needs "attach file _____" with respective category when inputting. Folder ID's will be ready and identified.. Can I ask you about the details of them?

Lets say for example I went on vacation have have many pictures and I want each location in a different folder.
I would want the custom menu button to have, "attach file Folder A.... attach file Folder B...." and so on

@AndrewChung Please [edit] the question to clarify it.
